# How to Change "me" in Gmail

Tags: gmail

In Gmail, my email address is replaced by "me" in emails and chats, etc.

Is there a way to replace this "me" by anything else, such as the actual name of the person?

[Sometimes "me" is not actually me!](http://blogoscoped.com/archive/2007-07-05-n27.html)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Gmail will always show "me" for your Gmail address.

If you are using "send mail as" addresses, untick "Treat as alias" and we should stop showing "me" for those addresses; this is the preferred option for addresses that you send mail as but do not reflect your personal identity, such as mailing lists.

If you are seeing a problem with senders who have me@domain.com as their email address, you can correct that issue by updating their information in your Gmail Contacts.

Comment: Good suggestion for "send mail as", but does this work for changing  "me" in GTalk chats as well?

Comment: I was thinking maybe someone developed a lab option for this feature. i.e. instead of displaying "me", it could just display my name :)